# Automatically refreshing iframe src in angular material modal

Tags: angular, youtube, angular-material, modal-dialog

I am beginner in Angular 9 and angular material.

I have component, which showing in Material Modal. In this component, there is an iframe and iframe src value passing from parent component.

**Problem is:** When opening the modal, after certain time it's resetting iframe. So after playing the video, few seconds later, automatically paused the video with 00:00. So when I am playing again, it's playing from beginning.

Bellow is my code structure

**Module.ts**

```
 entryComponents: [VideoModalComponent,...]
```

**Video-modal.component.ts**

```
  import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
  import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
  import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-video-modal',
    templateUrl: './video-modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./video-modal.component.scss']
  })
  export class VideoModalComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
      public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  }
```

**video-modal.component.html**

```
<iframe [width]="(data.videoWidth - 50)" [height]="data.videoHeight"
    [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(data.videoUrl)" frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**section.component.ts**

```
openPromoModal(): void {
    this.dialog.open(VideoModalComponent, {
      width: this.videoWidth + 'px',
      data: {
        videoUrl: this.promotionalVideo.url,
        videoWidth: this.videoWidth,
        videoHeight: this.videoHeight
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: As a general rule, don't sanitize URLs directly in the template. Sanitize them in the controller and pass the sanitized URL to the `[src]` property. If you call directly in the template, it will be invoked multiple times due to change detection.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelD now it's working fine.

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from my comment, it is not a good idea to sanitize URLs directly in the template. It will be invoked multiple times due to change detection.

Better way would be to sanitize them in the controller and pass the sanitized URL to the `[src]` property.